# Сборщик аргументов конструктора

Tags: php

Есть ли сборщик параметров конструктора в PHP?
Например:

```
class LinkTemplate {

private $name;
private $link;
private $full_link;
private $description;
private $image;

function __construct($data = array()){
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->link = $data['link'];

}

}
```

Нужно, чтобы массив $data был распределен по переменным класса, а те, в свою очередь, были помещены в один массив. По сути, нужно избежать конструкции инициализаций:

```
$this->link = $data['link'];
```

Во-первых, хочется избежать проверок: `if(isset($data['link'])) {$this->link = $data['link'];}`

Comment: Ни черта не понял из вопроса :)
____

@Oleg Ponomarchuk, да уже достаточно прочитал раз, но так и не понял, в каком смысле ты хочешь избавится от конструкций инициализаций $this->link = $data['link'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я не понял автора вопроса, но смею предположить, что он хочет что-то вроде вот такой вот конструкции :)

```
function __construct ($data = array()) {
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, правильно предположили. Только, может, есть более ООП решения. Может, абстрактный класс подключить? Потому как я не знаю точно, есть ли такой `$this->$key` в `$data`

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, так дело в том, что если он там есть, значит он там есть, а если его нету, значит его там нету.

Comment: К примеру, в переменных класса

    private $name;
    private $link;
    private $full_link;
    private $description;
    private $image;

Можно держать $value по умолчанию, на тот случай, если его нет в $data.

Comment: Коммент к коду перед foreach ($data as $key => $value) - лучше проверить, что нам дали массив.

Comment: @Ale_x поправил :)

Comment: Можно чуть короче: ``foreach ((array)$data as $key => $value) {..}``

Comment: а можно просто написать

   function __construct(array $data = array())

и не волноваться

Comment: @Etki, да, можно и так :)

Answer (score 1):

Кто же ищет лёгких путей?

```
// долой наследование!
trait LazyConstructorTrait {

    protected function init($arguments)
    {
        $parameters = (new ReflectionObject($this))
            ->getConstructor()
            ->getParameters();

        foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {
            $argument = isset($arguments[$key])
                      ? $arguments[$key]
                      : $parameter->getDefaultValue(); // обращаем-внимание-1

            $this->{$parameter->name} = $argument;
        }
    }
}

// пример
class A {
    use LazyConstructorTrait; // не теряем трейт

    protected $a;
    protected $b;
    protected $c;
    protected $d;

    public function __construct($a, $b, $d = 'someVal')
    {
        $this->init(func_get_args());
    }
}

$a = new A('a', 'b'); // $a->a == 'a', $a->b == 'b', $a->c == null, $a->d == 'someVal'
// или
$a = new A('a', 'b', 'd'); // $a->a == 'a', $a->b == 'b', $a->c == null, $a->d == 'd'

var_dump($a);
```

По поводу заметки `обращаем-внимание-1`: вызов метода `ReflectionParameter::getDefaultValue()` бросает исключение при обращении к обязательному параметру, но если вы пропустите такой параметр, то скрипт завалится еще в момент вызова. Поэтому, игнорируем.

**Плюсы**:

- подключаем в любом классе и не беспокоим предков
- работаем как обычно, с phpDoc и подсказками IDEшки

**Минусы**:

- PHP >= 5.4
- *может еще что-то :)*